# is a labeled instruction going to be executed without a branching instruction when it is in an instruction order?

Tags: if-statement, mips, branch

`beq $s0, $s1, Lab1
add $s2, $s0, $s1
Lab1: sub $s1, $s1, $s0`

when $s0, $s1 are not equal line2 will be executed. is line3 going to be executed after line2?
or can line3 be executed when only the if statement is satisfied and send to Lab1?

I hope I made my question clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course.  The label is a feature of assembly language.&nbsp; While it corresponds to something in machine code --  (a location, not an instruction), the label does not actually exist as far as the processor is concerned.  There is no [come from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMEFROM) in machine code :)

Comment: thank you for your comment. if the label does not actually exist then when beq is satisfied how can lab1 be run after skipping add instruction on line2?

Comment: Labels aren't run, only instructions are run.  And each instruction has a precise and published behavior.  See more in my answer below.

Comment: now I get what you mean by the label isn't run. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every instruction tells the processor what instruction comes next.

Let's take a closer look at the `add` instruction.

It computes the sum, places that into the target register, and also, in parallel, increments the program counter by 4 — definitively telling the processor that the next instruction is the next one in address order sequence.

---

A `nop` instruction is commonly said to do nothing — it even stands for no-operation — but it does increment the pc, so technically it doesn't do nothing at all.

---

As a mentor to assembly language students, I find it useful to emphasize the program counter.

Experienced assembly language programmers often overlook the program counter as and because it is so fundamental to the operation of the processor.  So, let's talk about it for a moment.

Every instruction tells the processor what instruction comes next: each instruction updates the program counter, and, this update to the program counter is the mechanism by which each instruction tells the processor what is next.  Each instruction has its own memory address; a given instruction executes because the program counter held its address.  Sequential operation isn't magic — each instruction has to tell the processor what is next (i.e. has to update the pc).

Programs can also interact with the program counter, calling (`jal`) captures the program counter next into the `$ra` register for the subroutine or function to use to return back control of the processor to the caller.

Only slightly overly simplified, within a subroutine or function, moving the program counter backwards forms a loop — the processor goes backward to re-execute something it already did before; moving it forwards skip something, as needed for if-then or if-then-else.

But each instruction has well-defined way that it modifies the program counter, whether it appears to be explicit or implicit.

---

```
          Assembly              Machine Code Operation
    beq $s0, $s1, Lab1    # skip 1 instruction on condition $s0 == $s1
    add $s2, $s0, $s1     # not skipped if $s0 != $s1: next is pc+4
Lab1:                     # no machine code for this
    sub $s1, $s1, $s0     # run after beq when $s0 == $s1 -or else- after add
```

In assembly language, the label informs the assembler how to translate an instruction that uses it.  `Lab1` will be associated with a location, an address, here the address of the `sub` instruction.

The `beq` is a conditional pc-relative branch.  Thus, the value it wants is the delta between the pc-next (of itself) and the branch target, here `Lab1`.  A delta of 0 would cause no instructions to be skipped, and a delta of 1 will cause 1 instruction to be skipped.  Here we want to skip 1 instruction, so the delta will be 1.  There is literally a 1 in the machine code for that `beq`.

After executing the `beq` the processor will have been told (based on the specified eq condition) whether it will branch or not.  It does this by either adjusting the pc to pc+4 -or- to pc+4+delta.

Both the other instructions are what we call sequential so they inform the processor that pc-next is pc+4.  Knowing that you can follow the full sequencing on either the conditional branch taken or not taken.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation! Your explanation about how sequential operation isn't magic, why not to overlook the program counter and how the delta value works nailed where my confusion is at.